# GCC Pragma region error: expected expression before ‘#pragma’

Tags: gcc, region, pragma

I'm trying to fold elements in an array with `#pragma region` and `#pragma endregion` directives, but every time I compile it I get:

```
gcc -ffreestanding -fshort-wchar -fno-stack-protector -Wall -Wno-implicit-function-declaration -c main.c -o main.o
main.c:16:13: error: expected expression before ‘#pragma’
   16 |     #pragma region ExclamationMark
      |             ^~~~~~
```

Here's a minimal reproducible example:

```
#define FontHeight 16

typedef struct { unsigned char g[FontHeight]; } Glyph;

#define GLYPH(_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,_9,_10,_11,_12,_13,_14,_15,_16) (Glyph){{_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,_9,_10,_11,_12,_13,_14,_15,_16}}
#define EMPTY_GLYPH (Glyph){{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}}

Glyph Font[] = {
    EMPTY_GLYPH,
    EMPTY_GLYPH,
    EMPTY_GLYPH,
    EMPTY_GLYPH,
    // and so on...
    #pragma region ExclamationMark
    GLYPH(
        0b00000000,
        0b00000000,
        0b00000000,
        0b00001000,
        0b00001000,
        0b00001000,
        0b00001000,
        0b00001000,
        0b00001000,
        0b00001000,
        0b00000000,
        0b00001000,
        0b00001000,
        0b00000000,
        0b00000000,
        0b00000000
    ),
    #pragma endregion ExclamationMark
};
```

The two aforementioned directives were supported in GCC v13 (I'm using GCC 13.1.1 on Arch Linux), but even so GCC throws me an error - this should at most be a warning as far as I know and my toolchain doesn't promote any warnings to errors.

The reason I want to do this is because the elements I'm trying to fold are multiple lines long, themselves simplified by using `#define` directives in a header file. Permalink to source file is [here](https://github.com/somecollagist/Derecho/blob/230e1852cadd6cb2272d98ffb8ae0fa338aedd6a/src/font.c).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What happens in the code *before* the `#pragma`? Errors like that usually depend on an earlier error, unrelated to the line the error is reported on.

Comment: [Works for me](https://godbolt.org/z/oKfc1sWTh) in the simplest case. Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that we can run locally, not just an fragment.

Comment: Similarly, it works for me in a simple case, a region and endregion with nothing inbetween. Before the pragma, there are a series of EMPTY_GLYPH values, which are a special case of GLYPH, defined as the following:

```typedef struct { uint8_t g[FontHeight]; } Glyph;

#define GLYPH(_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,_9,_10,_11,_12,_13,_14,_15,_16) (Glyph){{_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,_9,_10,_11,_12,_13,_14,_15,_16}}
#define EMPTY_GLYPH (Glyph){{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}}```

before that is just `#include` directives.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question to add details and code.

Comment: Also note that errors can exist in header files and be reported in the source file they are included in. You should really try to create a [mre]. Chances are you might even figure out the problem yourself while creating the example.

Comment: It seems to me like GCC 13 stopped accepting `#pragma`s inside expressions, like `Font[]`'s initialization, even for `#pragma region` that does nothing. I don't see the issue with GCC 12. Maybe it's a bug that [has to be reported](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugs/).